# Surprising behaviour when iterating over a list while modifying it

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I'm aware that this is an example of code you should never write, and I'm not asking for the right approach. My concern is that I don't understand its behaviour, so I was hoping someone could shed light on it:

```
def foo(list_of_chars):
    '''Returns the set of words that can be obtained by removing one character from list_of_chars.'''
    result = set()
    my_copy = list(list_of_chars)
    for elem in my_copy:
        my_copy.remove(elem)
        result.add(''.join(my_copy))
        my_copy = list(list_of_chars)
    return result
```

I would have expected either behaviour from this function (let's say `list_of_chars` is `['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']`):

1. the code runs flawlessly because we restore `my_copy` at the end of each iteration, so when the `for` loop assigns the next element to elem it is the same as if we had never touched the list (so we do iterate over 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o');
2. the code fails miserably because the assignment at the end of the loop is somehow ignored, so we first remove 'h', skip 'e', remove 'l', skip the next 'l', and then remove 'o' -- and possibly crash.

What actually happens is stranger: we iterate over 'h', 'l', 'l', 'o', so 'e' is skipped, but it's the only character that is skipped. Other examples behave in the same way: only the second element of `list_of_chars` is overlooked. Can someone explain this? (Python 2 and 3 yield the same result).

Comment: `"iterating over a list while modifying it"` : horns blaring, red light pops out...

Comment: See first line of my question. Again, that is not my point.

Comment: I am not commenting on the question itself. Haven't even gone through the first line (don't have time to go through it). Pardon if it was offensive. Just that the title has that effect. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop does not "read" `my_copy` again on every iteration, but `my_copy.remove` does.

```
for elem in my_copy:
    my_copy.remove(elem)
```

On the first iteration, `my_copy` in both lines refers to the same object. You're actually modifying the object `for` iterates over. However, at the end of the iteration, you replace `my_copy` with something else. The `for` loop retains its original object reference, but `my_copy.remove` refers to the current version of `my_copy`. So now the object the `for` loop iterates over and the object that you `remove` an element from are two different objects.

Hence `remove` interferes with the loop only on the first iteration.

Comment: ... whereas using `my_copy[:]` when I restore the list would have led the `for` and the `remove` lines to act on the same list. Thanks, that was tricky.

Comment: Assuming you mean `my_copy[:] = ...`, in which case yes, you'd be modifying the existing object.

Comment: Yes exactly, I should write expressions in full.